# How can I get the box height of an element using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, height

I've tried using the jQuery `.height()` function to get the height of an element but it seems to be ignoring padding and margins.

How can I get the size of an element's box using Javascript and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use outerHeight

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to wrap the div with padding/margins within another div and get the height of the container div?

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="divWithPadding">
   content
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not doable in my case, but it's good to know of this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Example using [outerHeight();](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

http://jsfiddle.net/HruqF/2/